# How do i set in the module.config.php file a parameter of type array in ZEND 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

this is a part of my file:

```
'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type' => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '[:controller[/:action]][/:param1]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'action' => 'index',
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                            'param1' => 'tralala'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
```

So, instead of **param1**, I want to define an array, How can I do that ? When i set the keys in the array:

```
 $this->redirect()->toRoute(null, array(
                        'controller' => 'user',
                        'action' =>  'confirm',
                        'param1' => array(
                                        'email'=>$request->getPost('mail'),
                                        'name'=>$request->getPost('name')
                                    )
                    ));
```

and accessing it :

```
$params = $this->params()->fromRoute('param1');
        var_dump($params); exit();
```

Obviously my code does not work. It is possible to set an array in the route, or I'm asking stupid thing s here ? thx

Comment: How would you expect an array to appear in the URL? I don't think you can use non-scalar values as route params.

Comment: then, how do i make a redirect with an array parameter ? can you post me an answer ? thx a lot !!!

Comment: You don't. In your example, you'd pass email and name as separate params.

Comment: if I pass separatly 2 parameters in my case it works, but it looks weird in the url, cuz i have mydomain/mycontroller/myfunction/my_email_address/my_name. it looks weirds. So I thought that maybe it is a way to pass an array with  the redirect, but because im a totally  newbie in Zend 2 I don't know how to do it. so if you show me  i would really appreaciate it :)

Comment: It probably can't be done and definitely shouldn't be attempted. If you want to hide that info put it in session data. I'd be awkward if a leading-search-engine indexes urls with emails in them anyway.

Comment: I guess im stuck with zf2